# Purchase Order Payment Method

Tags: magento2

i have different payment Methods on my Checkout page i have also Purchase Oder payment Method on my checkout page i want purchase order payment method for just login customer how i achieve this in magento2

Comment: You need to restrict payment method by code using observer

Answer (score 0):

you can create a custom module and create an event observer [ For Event "payment_method_is_active" ] to make Purchase Order Payment disable for Guest user.

I assume your custom module name is **Company_MyModule**

**step 1)**

create **events.xml** under ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/etc***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">        
    <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="MyModule_Pobycustomer" instance="Company\MyModule\Observer\DisablePoPayguest" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**step 2)**

Create the observer class **DisablePoPayguest.php** under **YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/Observer**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Company\MyModule\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;



class DisablePoPayguest implements ObserverInterface
{

    protected $logger;

    protected $_customerSession;


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory
     */
    protected $customerFactory;

    public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $loggerInterface, \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session, CustomerFactory $_customerFactory)
    {
        $this->logger           = $loggerInterface;
        $this->_customerSession = $session;
        $this->customerFactory  = $_customerFactory;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $result          = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        $method_instance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
        if ($method_instance->getCode() == 'purchaseorder') {            
            if (!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {       
                $result->setData('is_available', false);
            } 
        }
    }
}
```